# I cannot override a file in Strapi CMS

Tags: javascript, service, strapi

I try to override file using path "extensions\strapi-plugin-content-manager\services\ContentManager.js" and get every time an error: "error TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined".

The contents of the file that needs to be overwritten have not yet been changed

Strapi v3.0.0-beta.17.4

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:
You need to remove **"strapi-plugin"** in the path, like this:

```
extensions\content-manager\services\ContentManager.js
```